# Trying to make a linear regression model in R

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression

The data I have is below:

```
Geographic Area    2000         2001         2002         2003         2004     2005 
Arizona            4779736   4780138         4798834      51689934     5052356
```

I want the years to be the x-axis and the actual values to be the y-axis.

I've tried:

```
x <- seq(2000, 2005, by = 1)
y <- seq(4533372, 4671825, by 10000)
```

How can I plot the year and total population?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. Do you want to *model* the data (which is what CIAndrews seems to have understood), or is this about *plotting* `Geographic Area` vs. the years? Can you please add data in a reproducible format using e.g. `dput`? Currently your dataset has more columns than data.

Answer (score 2):

Maurits Evers asks a good question. Do you want the model? Then do:

```
dat <- data.frame("year" = c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004),
                   "population" = c(4779736,4780138,4798834,5168993,5052356))

model <- lm(population ~ year, data = dat)
```

But you're asking for a plot and there is a solution with `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(aes(x = years, y = population), data = dat) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

`geom_smooth()` fits a linear regression model to your data, inserts the regression line and also a ribbon to show the confidence intervals.

Maybe this is what you're looking for.

[image]